# Alternate 2 constants with setInterval

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

Hopefully this is a simple one. Done it dozens of times but cannot remember or have I found a reference. How can I alternate two constants at `3500ms` using `setInterval`.

For example, can I alternate `paths1` and `paths2` as shown below?

```
const paths = {
  path1: 'path1',
  path2: 'path2'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setInterval` and a ternary operator like so:

```js
const paths = {
  path1: 'path1',
  path2: 'path2'
}

var myPath = paths.path1;

setInterval(function() {
  myPath = myPath == paths.path2 ? paths.path1 : paths.path2;
  console.log(myPath);
}, 3500);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two values to switch between:

```
var mypath = 'path1';
setInterval(()=> mypath = mypath==='path1'? 'path2':'path1', 3500);
```